# ListView, ItemTemplate - How to: deliver results template

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

Can you help me with ListView, ItemTemplate, Label controls way of delivering the results. Here's my code:

```
    <asp:ListView ID="lstViewResultsUpdate" runat="server" DataItem="Object">

<LayoutTemplate>
    <h3>Listing</h3>
    <blockquote>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>                        
    </blockquote>
</LayoutTemplate>

<ItemSeparatorTemplate>
    <hr />
</ItemSeparatorTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>

Label2 - <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label2" Text='<%# GetAllValues(((Dictionary<string,List<string>>)Container.DataItem)["Test1"]) %>' />

<br/><br/><hr>

Label3 - <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label3" Text='<%# GetAllValues(((Dictionary<string,List<string>>)Container.DataItem)["Test2"]) %>' />

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

The codebedind is:

```
    public string GetAllValues(object lst)
    {

        List<string> lstOfStr = (List<string>)lst;
        //lstOfStr.Clear();

        string allValues = "";

        foreach (string str in lstOfStr)

            allValues += "," + str;

        return allValues;
    }
```

...and the result is:

```
Label2 - Label2item1, Label2item2, Label2item3, etc.

<hr>

Label3 - Label3item1, Label3item2, Label3item3, etc.
```

How to make the result:

```
Label2 - Label2item1

<hr>

Label3 - Label3item1

Label2 - Label2item2

<hr>

Label3 - Label3item2

Label2 - Label2item3

<hr>

Label3 - Label3item4
```

Answer (score 0):

I have difficulties with codebehind part:

```
  public static IEnumerable<Article> GetArticles()
```

{         // data access code not shown      }

How to convert the code form my first post to code in this public static method?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. Environment.Newline is the way I'd go.

```
  allValues += Environment.NewLine + "," + str;
```